# using awk substr

Tags: awk

I have file with lines like so:

```
1       17      A       G       R:560:500:60:10.71%:1.6329E-19  Pass:1.0:276:0:57:0:1E0 15      17      0       0       R:24:20:4:16.67%:5.461E-2 R:22:20:2:9.09%:2.4419E-1 R:27:24:3:11.11%:1.1792E-1 R:26:23:3:11.54%:1.1765E-1 A:16:16:0:0%:1E0 A:23:23:0:0%:1E0 A:11:10:1:9.09%:5E-1
1       36      C       T       Y:560:499:61:10.89%:7.7026E-20  Pass:1.0:275:0:58:0:1E0 15      17      0       0       Y:24:20:4:16.67%:5.461E-2 Y:22:20:2:9.09%:2.4419E-1 Y:27:24:3:11.11%:1.1792E-1 Y:26:23:3:11.54%:1.1765E-1 C:16:16:0:0%:1E0 C:23:23:0:0%:1E0 C:11:10:1:9.09%:5E-1
```

I have been previously using the following awk on liner to extract the first character of each field from $11 onwards.

```
awk '{n=11; while (n<18) {{$n = substr($n, 0, 1)} n++} print $0}'
```

I am looking for an easy way to modify it so I can extract only the percentages from these fileds (the value after the 4th colon of the field). The output would look like this:

```
1       17      A       G       R:560:500:60:10.71%:1.6329E-19  Pass:1.0:276:0:57:0:1E0 15      17      0       0       16.67% 9.09% 11.11% 11.54% 0% 0% 9.09%
1       36      C       T       Y:560:499:61:10.89%:7.7026E-20  Pass:1.0:275:0:58:0:1E0 15      17      0       0       16.67% 9.09% 11.11% 11.54% 0% 0% 9.09%
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will print the percentage including the "%":

```
split($5, arr, ":"); print arr[5]
```

Adjust the field number in the `split()` statement to suit your data.

You don't need to use a `while` loop and manage the increment variable yourself, just use a `for` loop. Here is a complete, working script using the technique shown above and a `for` loop:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} {for (n = 11; n < 18; n++) {split($n, arr, ":"); $n = arr[5]}; print $0}'
```

Sample output:

```
1   17  A   G   R:560:500:60:10.71%:1.6329E-19  Pass:1.0:276:0:57:0:1E0 15  17  0   0   16.67%  9.09%   11.11%  11.54%  0%  0%  9.09%
1   36  C   T   Y:560:499:61:10.89%:7.7026E-20  Pass:1.0:275:0:58:0:1E0 15  17  0   0   16.67%  9.09%   11.11%  11.54%  0%  0%  9.09%
```

Comment: awk '{n=11; while (n<18) {{$n = substr($n, 0, 1)} n++} print $0}'

Comment: I am having trouble incorporating it in to the awk one liner.         awk '{n=11; while (n<18) {{$n = split($n, arr,":" )} n++} print $0}'     is giving me just the number of elements in each array.

Comment: @user1308144: Please see my edited answer. `split()` puts the results in the named array and returns the number of parts.